# Synchronizing subdirectory with root directory

Tags: linux, ssh, putty

I have files like this on my linux web server:

- folder1/ <- main, this is where users of my page are led to
- folder1/testing/ <- copy of folder1(without folder1/testing/) to modify and optimize without disturbing the main version.

How do I synchronize folder1/ with the contents of folder1/testing/, so that folder1/ looks like folder1/testing/?

Comment: Another job for `rsync`, but really you should be using a [VCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control).

Comment: Be more specific. Remember the question is not "Which program to use" but "How do I synchronize folder1/ with the contents of folder1/testing/, so that folder1/ looks like folder1/testing/?"

Comment: This was a comment and not an answer because I *just* gave an `rsync` example in the question before your question.

Comment: @jordanm true, but generally you don't want to develop on the master (read "deployed") version. VCS should be entirely confined to the testing subdirectory in this case (which should be completely outside of the deployed version, btw.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are mentioning ssh/putty I expect you have shell access to the box. The directory setup is slightly cumbersome, having the testing version outside of the master copy is better. Hence:

1. move the testing directory outside of master

   ```
   mv folder1/testing folder1_testing
   ```
2. move current master version elsewhere - note that at this point the web becomes inaccessible until you get to the next step

   ```
   mv folder1 folder1_saved
   ```
3. copy the previously testing version to the proper location

   ```
   cp -a folder1_testing folder1
   ```
4. if you are unable to solve this in a different manner, symlink the testing version to the previous place to be able it access it via web at the same place:

   ```
   ln -vs folder1_testing folder1/testing
   ```